# XPTY0019 A step in a path expression (that is not the last step) is returning atomic values, which is not permitted. ERROR

Tags: xpath, tibco, xpath-2.0

I have a input structure with choice input like:
Work
 -Choices(Developer/Tester/Support)
 -Developer(inside Developer i have multiple Tools and i need to initialize that in an integer)
  -Tools*

i mapped is like : int count = XPath.evalAsInt("xpath://\n\n xsd:int(number(count($Work/Developer/Tools)))\n );

But it's throwing an error:
org.genxdm.xpath.v20.err.ConcreteErrException: [XPTY0019] A step in a path expression (that is not the last step) is returning atomic values, which is not permitted.
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:1299)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.AxisStepExpr.accept(AxisStepExpr.java:34)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:1584)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.ApplyOrderingModeQmExpr.accept(ApplyOrderingModeQmExpr.java:26)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:1059)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.RelativePathQmExpr.accept(RelativePathQmExpr.java:50)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:1052)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.RelativePathQmExpr.accept(RelativePathQmExpr.java:50)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:1052)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.RelativePathQmExpr.accept(RelativePathQmExpr.java:50)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:1052)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.RelativePathQmExpr.accept(RelativePathQmExpr.java:50)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:1052)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.RelativePathQmExpr.accept(RelativePathQmExpr.java:50)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:1052)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.RelativePathQmExpr.accept(RelativePathQmExpr.java:50)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:1052)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.RelativePathQmExpr.accept(RelativePathQmExpr.java:50)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:1052)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.RelativePathQmExpr.accept(RelativePathQmExpr.java:50)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:563)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.FunctionCallQmExpr.accept(FunctionCallQmExpr.java:36)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:563)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.FunctionCallQmExpr.accept(FunctionCallQmExpr.java:36)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.visit(QmExprAnalyzer.java:563)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.sa.model.impl.FunctionCallQmExpr.accept(FunctionCallQmExpr.java:36)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.QmExprAnalyzer.analyze(QmExprAnalyzer.java:198)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.XPathQmExprCompiler.compile(XPathQmExprCompiler.java:53)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.factories.XPathQmExprCompiler.compile(XPathQmExprCompiler.java:41)
    at org.genxdm.processor.xpath.v20.XPath2Toolkit.prepare(XPath2Toolkit.java:113)
    at com.tibco.be.functions.xpath.XPath2Helper.a(SourceFile:339)
    at com.tibco.be.functions.xpath.XPath2Helper.a(SourceFile:150)
    at com.tibco.be.functions.xpath.XPath2Helper.evalAsInt(SourceFile:259)
    at com.tibco.be.functions.xpath.XPathHelper.evalAsInt(SourceFile:295)
    at com.tibco.be.functions.xpath.XPathHelper.evalAsInt2(SourceFile:316)
    at be.gen.Rules.processRequest$processRequest_a.execute(processRequest.java:33)
    at com.tibco.cep.kernel.core.rete.ReteWM.resolveConflict(SourceFile:401)
    at com.tibco.cep.kernel.core.rete.ReteWM.void(SourceFile:377)
    at com.tibco.cep.kernel.core.rete.ReteWM.assertObject(SourceFile:1729)
    at com.tibco.cep.runtime.session.impl.RuleSessionImpl.assertObject(RuleSessionImpl.java:1455)
    at com.tibco.cep.runtime.scheduler.impl.WorkerBasedControllerV2$2.doTxnWork(WorkerBasedControllerV2.java:483)
    at com.tibco.cep.kernel.core.rete.BeTransaction.run(SourceFile:156)
    at com.tibco.cep.kernel.core.rete.BeTransaction.execute(SourceFile:101)
    at com.tibco.cep.runtime.scheduler.impl.WorkerBasedControllerV2.executeTask(WorkerBasedControllerV2.java:493)
    at com.tibco.cep.runtime.scheduler.impl.WorkerBasedControllerV2$WorkerTask.run(WorkerBasedControllerV2.java:521)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at com.tibco.cep.runtime.util.CustomBEManagedThread.run(CustomBEManagedThread.java:24)

Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the message probably means that the value of $Work is an atomic value, so you need to look at the code that sets this variable up. (This code would be rather more use to us than the lengthy stack trace). Incidentally, your code `xsd:int(number(count(xxxx)))` seems very strange: `count()` returns an integer, which you are then converting to a double, only to convert it back to an integer.

Comment: Hey Michael,I have tried below combinations as well, so basically here i am trying to initialize the var "Count" as int and then mapping the number of occurrence of Tools in that, but it is giving me atomic value error.  

int count = XPath.evalAsInt("xpath://\n\n xsd:int(count($Work/Developer/Tools))\n );

Comment: As I said, the error is almost certainly in how you set up the variable $Work. (I don't know the tibco API so I can't help you any further than that).